# Why am I not getting synchronized access in my code?

Tags: java, synchronization

```
class Caller extends Thread
{


    String s;



    Caller(String s)
    {

        this.s=s;
    }


    void call(String msg)
    {
        synchronized (this)
        {
            System.out.print("["+msg);

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            System.out.println("]");
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

    }   

    public void run()
    {


        call(s);
    }

}


public class SynchronisedBlock {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Caller c=new Caller("hi");
        Caller c1=new Caller("li");
        Caller c2=new Caller("wi");

        c.start();
        c1.start();
        c2.start();


    }

}


    public class SynchronisedBlock {

        public static void main(String[] args) {


            Caller c=new Caller("hi");
            Caller c1=new Caller("li");
            Caller c2=new Caller("wi");

            c.start();
            c1.start();
            c2.start();


        }

    }
```

I am trying to get synchronized access to call() using synchronized block but not getting that feature.When I am putting call() method in another class then I am getting the required functionality but not in this code. What am I missing? Can anyone tell me why? Thanx in advance.

Comment: You are synchronizing on `this`, `this` varies each time for each `Caller` object. You need to have a common synchronizing object.

Comment: @svasa thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As @svasa has stated, you need to have a common synchronizing object.
The simplest working example for your code would be to use a shared `lock` object. Also, the `lock` is `final`  to prevent it from being replaced somewhere else in the code, you would end up synchronizing on different objects. (thanks to @P.J.Meisch):

```
class Caller extends Thread {

    String s;
    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    Caller(String s) {

        this.s = s;
    }

    void call(String msg) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.print("[" + msg);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            System.out.println("]");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

    }

    public void run() {

        call(s);
    }
```

Comment: please make your lock object final to prevent it from being replaced somewhere else in the code, you would end up synchronizing on different objects.

Comment: This is not the simplest approach. The simplest approach is to implement a `Runnable` instead of improperly extending `Thread`. Then `this` could work.

Answer (score 0):

If your `run` method were in a `Runnable` like it's supposed to be, instead of a `Thread`, which it's not, then you could pass the same `Runnable` instance to each thread and `this` would work as a synchronization object reference.